# Android EditText return Vietnamese wrong format

Tags: android

I'm doing a Android project and facing a problem with EditText when I type Vietnamese.
Example, when i type the word "thử" into EditText and get string from it.

```
String text = edittext.getText().toString()
```

It always returns a String object with 4 characters "t", "h", "ư" and the accent character.
But if i create a String object by code like:`String text = "thử";`. It only contains 3 characters "t", "h" and "ử". So they do not match when I compare them. I want the String object contain 3 characters, not 4 characters.
I also think about a way that loop through all characters to replace them manually. But Vietnamese has 12 vowels and 6 accents so that it makes me have to check 72 cases. I don't think it is a good way.
 Anyway to get proper text from EditText? Or any good way to replace the text manually?
**UPDATE:**
I have found why the EditText always return weird String. It is cause by the phone keyboard app. I am using LG Magna and using default keyboard app. The app always encodes seperately base vowels and accents everything i input. I have just installed another keyboard app, then it works like a charm.
Now, I have to find a way to make sure that the text always returns properly from any keyboard app.

Comment: you input text from real phone or virtual device ?

Comment: @GiapLee : I type text from real phone

Answer (score 0):

Android use UTF-8 codepage, so please be sure that you're typing your vietnamese symbols using those UTF-8 but not any kind of *Windows-1258`*

Comment: Thanks barmaley, but I type text directly from my android phone. How could it be Windows-1258 codepage?